# Freemarker List inside a a table

Tags: list, html-table, freemarker

I'm trying to generate a table with freemarker.

```
<table class="timeline">
        <tr>
            <#list children as child >
                <td class="timeline-item"><a href="${child.url}">${child.title}</a></td>
                <td><img class="sitelink_arrow" src="images/arrow.png"/></td>
            </#list>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This will generate an error :

> Was expecting one of: ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... <_INCLUDE> ...
>   ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
>   ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... "${" ...
>   "#{" ...

If I put this list outside the table then it works just fine.
Any ideas ?

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't care if you do this inside or outside a HTML table, also your example is syntactically fine so it shouldn't give that error. Probably you look at the wrong place... Or something pre-processes the template so the above is not the final template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be look like this:

It is better if you post your code as well.
And full error also.

```
[#ftl]
<table id="timelineTable" class="timeline" align="left" width="100%">
    [#if children?? && children?size > 0] 
    [#list children as child]
    <tr>
        <td class="timeline-item">
            <a href="${child.url}">${child.title}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img class="sitelink_arrow" src="images/arrow.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    [/#list]
[#else] 
    No Details Available
[/#if]
```

Comment: Hey JustAName, have your problem resolved??? If yes, then what is the solution for that?? or its problem @your side?